# Okta - OAuthError - Unable to process the username transform. A required property is missing. Missing field email

Tags: reactjs, single-sign-on, okta, idp

I am integrating Okta in my React application for SSO. I use the following method to create token using redirect:

`https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-js#tokengetwithredirectoptions`

I am using `https://www.npmjs.com/package/@okta/okta-auth-js` package.

Users are directed to the Identity Provider (`idp`) in order to authenticate and then redirected to Okta once verification is successful.

The SSO works fine but when I keep the React application idle for sometime, I am getting the following error:

`OAuthError - Unable to process the username transform. A required property is missing. Missing field email.`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have configured email as the incoming claim from your IDP but Okta can't find it in the incoming assertion/token.